# MTKView - Draw on to Two Views at Once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal, metal-performance-shaders

### What I got

I am following Apple sample code **[AVCamPhotoFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCamPhotoFilter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017556)** to display camera feed on a `MTKView`.

### What I am trying to do

In addition to above `MTKView`, I need to display a second `MTKView`.  However, the second one will be displaying exactly the same content as the first one.  So I do not want to duplicate the code and do work twice.

### Current drawing method

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        var mirroring = false
        var rotation: Rotation = .rotate0Degrees

        syncQueue.sync {
            pixelBuffer = internalPixelBuffer
            mirroring = internalMirroring
            rotation = internalRotation
        }

        guard let drawable = currentDrawable,
            let currentRenderPassDescriptor = currentRenderPassDescriptor,
            let previewPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer else {
                return
        }

        // Create a Metal texture from the image buffer
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(previewPixelBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(previewPixelBuffer)

        if textureCache == nil {
            createTextureCache()
        }
        var cvTextureOut: CVMetalTexture?
        CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                  textureCache!,
                                                  previewPixelBuffer,
                                                  nil,
                                                  .bgra8Unorm,
                                                  width,
                                                  height,
                                                  0,
                                                  &cvTextureOut)
        guard let cvTexture = cvTextureOut, let texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cvTexture) else {
                print("Failed to create preview texture")

                CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
                return
        }

        if texture.width != textureWidth ||
            texture.height != textureHeight ||
            self.bounds != internalBounds ||
            mirroring != textureMirroring ||
            rotation != textureRotation {
            setupTransform(width: texture.width, height: texture.height, mirroring: mirroring, rotation: rotation)
        }

        // Set up command buffer and encoder
        guard let commandQueue = commandQueue else {
            print("Failed to create Metal command queue")
            CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
            return
        }

        guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {
            print("Failed to create Metal command buffer")
            CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
            return
        }

        guard let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: currentRenderPassDescriptor) else {
            print("Failed to create Metal command encoder")
            CVMetalTextureCacheFlush(textureCache!, 0)
            return
        }

        commandEncoder.label = "Preview display"
        commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState!)
        commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexCoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(textCoordBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
        commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
        commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(sampler, index: 0)
        commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.present(drawable) // Draw to the screen
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }
```

### Question

Is there a way I can simply pass on the texture to the second `MTKView` and draw without doing work twice?

Answer (score 4):

If you set the `framebufferOnly` property of the first `MTKView` to false, you can submit commands which read from its drawable texture. Then, you can use a blit command encoder to copy from the first drawable's texture to the second's, if they are compatible. Otherwise, you can draw a quad to the second drawable's texture with the first drawable's texture as the source for texturing the quad.

Personally, I think I would prefer all of the rendering to go to a texture of your own creation (not any drawable's texture). Then, copy/draw that to both of the drawable textures.

In any case, if you need the two views to update in perfect sync, you should set `presentsWithTransaction` to true for both views, synchronously wait (using `-waitUntilScheduled`) for the command buffer that does (at least) the copy/draw to the drawable textures, and then call `-present` directly on both drawables. (That is, don't use `-presentDrawable:` on the command buffer.)